# How to convert &#8211 to a character in android?

Tags: android, html, string, parsing

I read html code from my webpage to display in my app.
How can i convert these characters into String characters in Android?

```
&#8211 = -
&#8230 = ...
```

I know those two. But I would prefer a dynamic solution if possible.

Comment: Try `Html.fromHtml()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Html.fromHtml()` is used primarily for converting HTML tags into spans, returning a `Spanned` object that retains that formatting when applied to a `TextView`.

However, `Html.fromHtml()` can also handle converting some HTML-style entities into characters.